# MSI won't install packages error 1320

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

So I have an issue with installing programs keeps telling me the file name would be too long however I navigated to said folder and discovoered this in the address bar kkpo ;ooooooooooo i9o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The whole path counts as filename and cannot surpass 260 characters ([source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq#1TC=windows-7)):

If the length of the file name is an issue, one should be aware that the folder sturcture counts in to the file name length. So if the file is in a long list of subfolders or in a folder with a very ling name, that could cause problems as well.

```
FOLDER1/SUBFOLDER1/SUBFOLDER2/filename.ext = 35 characters, not 8.
```

This might not be a solution for your problem but should be taken into account.

You could try copying the file to the Desktop and run it there.

Comment: Yes I have tried this however the issue is in my registry somewhere as I cannot even rename a folder on my desktop but a file I have no problems renaming TBH I am sick of seeing this answer everywhere it is not helpful

Comment: I recommend including that in your question, what you already tried!